# How to install windows 8 without a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, windows-installation

I have a new [VivoPC VM40B](http://www.asus.com/ASUS_VivoPC/VivoPC_VM40B/) and usb mouse. Also I have windows 8.1 ISO. How to install windows 8 without a keyboard?

I'll be glad to any advice.

Comment: You can't you need both input devices ( a mouse ) and ( a keyboard. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's very simple. I downloaded a [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) and made Live USB with my Windows 8.1. Then I put Usb Driver into the computer, turned on the computer, and install of windows automatically started.

Comment: @shub, It has done.